# How to edit row name while using ag-grid react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid-react

i am using AG-Grid in react, I want to rename the row title count which appear automatically while using aggregation. the photo will help you to understand better.[image]

look at the row which says "United States" and then (1109) which is count of matching pairs i want to remove that count from there. can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the count from the group, add the following to the `autoGroupColumnDef`:

```
  const autoGroupColumnDef = {
      cellRendererParams: {
        suppressCount: true,
      },
    };
```

See this implemented in the [documentation example here](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grouping-single-group-column/#example-single-group-column-configuration)